# How to prove $|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i|\le \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, absolute-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

Let $n$ be a natural number and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are real numbers. Then prove that  $|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i|\le  \sqrt{n\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$.

At first I tried to prove for $n=2$ i.e, $|a_1+a_2|\le \sqrt{2(a_1^2+a_2^2)}$, but unable to proceed. Give me some hint to proceed.

Comment: It is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Divide by $n$ and it reduces to the [root-mean square inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality).

Comment: `I tried to prove for n=2` Both sides are non-negative, so square the inequality and group everything on one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's C-S:
$$\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n1^2\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}\geq\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2}=\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right|.$$
We can use also the following way.

Since our inequality is homogeneous and does not depend on the substitution $a_i\rightarrow-a_i$,

we can assume that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i=n.$

Thus, we need to prove that
$$n\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\geq n$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_i^2-1\right)\geq0$$ or 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(a_i^2-1-2(a_i-1)\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle P(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(a_i+x)^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(a_i^2+2xa_i+x^2)=nx^2+2x\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2\ge 0$

$P(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial of constant sign so $\Delta\le 0$.

$\Delta=4\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2-4n\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2\le 0\iff \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\le n\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2$

Which is the desired inequality after taking the square root, it is known as Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The result is trivial if $n=1,$ so suppose $n\geq 2.\ $ Note that $n-1\geq 1.$

$$ \sum_{cyc} (a_1-a_2)^2 \geq 0 $$

$$ \implies (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i ^2 \geq 2 \sum_{cyc} a_1a_2. $$

Adding $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i ^2$ to both sides gives:

$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i ^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 + 2 \sum_{cyc} a_1a_2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \right)^2. $$

Square rooting both sides gives the result.